# What's the time complexity of creating a database index for a column?

Tags: database, algorithm

I want to create an index for a database I have implemented using files. What's the time complexity of "creating" an index for one of the columns if I use B tree.

Comment: What's the solution you are looking for? 
It would be O(nlogn) roughly, but most time is consumed by disk IO.

Comment: I think time complexity is not the only thing to evaluate performance for your case. You are interacting with Disk, not only memory. So your algorithm needs to take that into account more than time complexity.